# How will I print a geometric progression using for loop in C

Tags: c

How to print a geometric progression in c program using for loop with an having an input of the number of terms you want for the progression
example
input: 5
output: 2 6 18 54 162

Comment: `int result = 2, iterations = 5; for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) { printf("%d ", result); result *= 3; }`

Comment: Have you tried something?  Is there something you can show that gives us the impression you don't want just somebody that works for free for you?